# Operational Error(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.3.138.130' (111)")

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to connect MySQL by using ip which I got from PhpMyAdmin using python. But I face **Operational Error(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.3.138.130' (111)")**

I know how to use mysql to connect to localhost

*I am following [this tutorial](https://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/connecting-to-mysql-with-python-2/)*

I have written following lines of code in python
I am using ubuntu terminal to run python code and I do have mysql-server installed on my laptop.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect('127.3.138.130','my_username','my_password','my_db_name')
```

So what the problem is ? how to solve this problem ,please explain me in very simple manner. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the server listens to outside requests. To do this go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on the server and edit:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

To:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

You may need to use `sudo` when editing the file.

You will need to restart the server after changing the configuration:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

You can also see what port is the server listening on (the default being 3306) in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Just look for a line that says:

```
port = 3306
```

Make sure you're connecting to through same port, this is how you can specify a port:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = '127.3.138.130', 
    user = 'my_username', 
    passwd = 'my_password', 
    db = 'my_db_name', 
    port = 3306 # should be same as in /etc/mysql/my.cnf on server.
)
```

Comment: I followed what is given in the answer but still could not get it to work. I then figured out that the "bind-address" parameter is in the "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf" file. Commented it out over there and it worked! Thanks for leading me there though!

Answer (score 0):

use 'pymysql' lib...it may help u....

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host=''127.3.138.130', port=3306, user='root', passwd='password', db='dbname')
```

Comment: This does not attempt to explain what's wrong with his code and how to fix it. This will work if the problemis the wrong port number, but if that's the case - you could have fixed it using the library he is already using as well by specifying the right port.